# How can I write or push json to a json file?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

So I am building this react app, where I have to create a json structure and then add this to a json file.
Here is the structure I have to build:

```
{
   "name": {
    "label": "Name",
    "type": "text",
    "operators": ["equal", "not_equal"],
    "defaultOperator": "not_equal"
},
   "age": {
    "label": "Age",
    "type": "number",
    "operators": [
      "equal",
      "not_equal",
      "less",
      "less_or_equal",
      "greater",
      "greater_or_equal",
      "between",
      "not_between",
      "is_empty",
      "is_not_empty"
    ]
},
"gender": {
  "label": "Gender",
  "type": "select",
  "listValues": {
      "male": "Male",
      "female": "Female"
  }
 }
}
```

After finishing with the json structure, I want to push this to a json file, which is the configuration file for a react library (react-awesome-query-builder). Now how can I write to a json file using JS? 
I know that I can use Node.js and use `fs` for this, but I am not sure how to use this in react. Perhaps there is a library I can use to do this?
Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: you cannot interact with the file system using javascript in the browser.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I think I found a way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it exactly as a traditional text file (because it is basically text). Meanwhile don't forget to give to your file the extension  `.json`!
It is when you will open it afterward that you will have to parse it as json wich is well handled by plenty of libraries

Comment: how do you write to a text file with javascript in the browser?

Comment: From the browser it is actually not possible I'm afraid! Although it would be a serious security issue... Meanwhile you can send a request to your backend (if any...) so that it writes it down

Answer (score 0):

Well... I guess I figured it out. Instead of using an external json file I tested the config file inside as a variable and it works. No need to use read/write from node.js or any of that.